# Convert RSA private key to bytes array

Tags: docusignapi

I need to pass a **private_key_bytes: the byte contents of the RSA private key** in **api_client.request_jwt_user_token()** API. How do I convert RSA private key to byte array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Python and using our SDK.
Here is a code snippet taken out of our [code examples](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-python) on GitHub:
(this line does it - `private_key = cls._get_private_key().encode("ascii").decode("utf-8")`

```
def _jwt_auth(cls):
    """JSON Web Token authorization"""
    api_client = ApiClient()
    api_client.set_base_path(DS_JWT["authorization_server"])

    # Catch IO error
    try:
        private_key = cls._get_private_key().encode("ascii").decode("utf-8")
    except (OSError, IOError) as err:
        return render_template(
            "error.html",
            err=err
        )

    try:
        cls.ds_app = api_client.request_jwt_user_token(
            client_id=DS_JWT["ds_client_id"],
            user_id=DS_JWT["ds_impersonated_user_id"],
            oauth_host_name=DS_JWT["authorization_server"],
            private_key_bytes=private_key,
            expires_in=3600
        )
```